# Apple will approve the build with these warnings?

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings

I have developed an app for iOS iPhone. I am receiving following warnings in the Xcode console part. When i upload an app to Appstore is there any chances of rejection of build ?

Warnings shown in console:
unnable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

Comment: Yes they will, Don't worry

Comment: While they will, you shouldn't be submitting apps with warnings. Rather solve the problem before submitting a sub par application.

Comment: Thanks guys , These warnings are related to storyboard constrains . However we have resolved all other warnings except this. Hope they will approve.